# What tenses does aorist in indicative mood in the New Testament usually express?

Tags: grammar

What tenses does aorist in indicative mood in the New Testament usually express? Can it express a continuous action in the present (like a verb in Present Progressive in English)? Can it express a future action? Can anyone, please, give an overview. Please, note that I am only interested in the N.T. aorist, that is, the Koine Greek aorist found in the New Testament and not the Attic Greek aorist. Also, I am only interested about aorist in indicative mood.

Comment: It would probably be better to ask about a specific text, as this *may* be off topic (especially if there ever comes to exist a site about the Greek language).

Comment: Also, there may be some special usage in a specific passage of interest to you that we could clue you in on. Even so, I intend to answer this for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The aorist tense "presents an occurrence in summary, viewed as a whole from the outside, without regard for the internal make-up of the occurrence."<sup>1</sup> Wallace explains,

> This contrasts with the present and imperfect, which portray the
>   action as an ongoing process. It may be helpful to think of the aorist
>   as taking a snapshot of the action while the imperfect (like the
>   present) takes a motion picture, portraying the action as it unfolds.
>
> [A footnote points out,] There is a difference between seeing the
>   aorist as undefined and seeing it as a summary tense, though the two
>   are closely related. In our view the aorist summarizes. It is thus not
>   undefined or unmarked. That is to say, it is not necessarily the
>   “default” tense that one would use unless he or she had reason to use
>   another. The key issue, it seems, is the tense-mood combination.
>   **Outside the indicative**, the aorist is hardly unmarked (statistically,
>   the present runs neck-and-neck with it). **However, in the indicative,
>   the aorist does appear to function this way, at least in narrative
>   literature.** The imperfect, (historical) present, perfect, and
>   pluperfect are all used in narrative, along with the aorist. But the
>   aorist is by far the most common. Thus, the analogy with a snapshot
>   seems appropriate, enabling the student to get a handle on the basic
>   notion of the aorist’s aspect.<sup>2</sup>

Wallace goes on to share a helpful analogy:

> Suppose I were to take a snapshot of a student studying for a mid-term
>   exam in intermediate Greek. Below the picture I put the caption,
>   “Horatio Glutchstomach studied for the mid-term.” From the snapshot
>   and the caption all that one would be able to state positively is that
>   Horatio Glutchstomach studied for the mid-term. Now in the picture you
>   notice that Horatio has his Greek text opened before him. From this,
>   you cannot say, “Because the picture is a snapshot rather than a
>   movie, I know that Horatio Glutchstomach only had his Greek text
>   opened for a split-second”! This might be true, but the snapshot does
>   not tell you this. All you really know is that the student had his
>   Greek text open. An event happened. From the picture you cannot tell
>   for how long he had his text open. You cannot tell whether he studied
>   for four hours straight (durative), or for eight hours, taking a ten
>   minute break every 20 minutes (iterative). You cannot tell whether he
>   studied successfully so as to pass the test, or whether he studied
>   unsuccessfully. **The snapshot does not tell you any of this. The
>   snapshot by itself cannot tell if the action was momentary,
>   “once-for-all”, repeated, at regularly recurring intervals, or over a
>   long period of time.** It is obvious from this crude illustration that
>   it would be silly to say that since I took a snapshot of Horatio
>   studying, rather than a movie, he must have studied only for a very
>   short time!<sup>3</sup>

Wallace further elaborates on the aorist in the indicative mood:

> In the indicative, the aorist usually indicates past time with
>   reference to the time of speaking (thus, “absolute time”). Aorist
>   participles usually suggest antecedent time to that of the main verb
>   (i.e., past time in a relative sense). There are exceptions to this
>   general principle, of course, but they are due to intrusions from
>   other linguistic features vying for control....
>
> Outside the indicative and participle, time is not a feature of the
>   aorist.<sup>4</sup>

In conclusion, we must avoid the dangers of saying too much or too little when the aorist tense occurs. The aorist doesn't exist "in a vacuum," so we must pay attention to when context is guiding us towards different meanings as it combines various linguistic features. **But we must also avoid saying too much** (i.e. saying the aorist *always* means "once-for-all" or "momentary" action).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Fanning, *Verbal Aspect*, 97. Cf. also McKay, “Time and Aspect,” 225.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Daniel B. Wallace, Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics: An Exegetical Syntax of the New Testament (Grand Rapids, MI: Zondervan, 1996), 555.</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>Ibid., 555.</sub>

<sup>4</sup> <sub>Ibid., 555.</sub>

Comment: WOW!! A very good answer. Thank you. I didn't have any specific verse in particular. I just wanted to have an overview of indicative mood aorist use in the New Testament.

Comment: @brilliant sounds good. I just figured I'd asks since there are some exceptional use cases.